# Overlapping mutli-line comments

Tags: syntax, comments, multiline

In C#, is there a reason why multi-line `/* */` comments can't overlap? This also applies to HTML (and I'm sure lots of other languages) too.

e.g.

```
/*

int a = SomeFunction();

/* int i = 0; */

int b = SomeFunction();

*/
```

won't compile.

When writing code I often want to quickly check the logic, and isolate certain parts by removing a section using multi-line comments, but then have to go through the code block replacing all multi-line comments with single line ones `//`.

I don't like using single line comments to comment-out code blocks (even though Visual Studio provides shortcuts to do this) as these then affect text comments when it comes to removing all comments in the block using the shortcut.

Is there a reason why the multi-line comment cannot mean: 'ignore *everything* between here'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid this is the way how it's designed.

I think you should use single line comments as much as possible. It's also much clearer when you are viewing the history of a file in source control. If you commented an entire method with /* */ then only two lines will appear changed, otherwise the entire method will have been changed (// added).

Comment: That's a good point about source control (I was just thinking about writing the code and removing the test comments before commiting) - but its definitely an issue.